# external javascript for greasemonkey? (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have a simple user script for greasemonkey and it works great. Now I want to exclude the script and

```
 $.getScript("http://www.my-domain.de/my-script.js");
```

doesn't work.

**my-script.js** is only

```
 $("input:text").css("background","tan");
```

Comment: Can't you do something like `@require http://urlhere`?

Comment: Wait, re-read question and I'm confused now,what do you want to exclude?

Comment: i only want to exclude 'my-script.js'

Comment: I guess you want to _execute_ it, not exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not finding you question very clear since why would you use `getSricpt` if you wanted to exclude a script.

Maybe I'm not getting the question at all, but, if you want to exclude a script in greasemonkey you can do so:

```
// @exclude http://www.my-domain.de/my-script.js
```

Se a brief explanation [here](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/helloworld/metadata.html) (Beware because I think this tutorial is/might outdated in some parts).

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: hmm...
i want to run http://www.my-domain.de/my-script.js
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
is requred and how to load an run my-script.js? getScript() does'n work for me.
thx for the help Trufa

Comment: i'm stupi: only need to put // @require http://www.my-domain.de/my-script.js in my *.user.js
thanx for your great help Trufa

Comment: @StevenMoss: Ok no problem!! but what I'm not getting is that you said you wanted to exclude, but you actually wanted to include?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in english and jquery :)

Comment: @StevenMoss: No problem at all! I wish you luck with both English and jQuery! :)